# execute a ESRI GP Service with a Button Control

Tags: javascript, function, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to allow a user to buffer a road based on an atribute field using an ESRI GP Service.  The GP service is working as expected, but now how do I execute this task on the web page?  I would like to control this with a button.

Firstly I define the variable for the GP Service:

```
 var roadBuffer = new Geoprocessor("URL");
```

Then I create the Button:

```
var myButton = new Button({
           //label: "Click me!",
           onClick: function () {
               // Do something:
               runBufferTool(??????("?????").?????);
           }
       }, "BufferButton");
```

Then I would need to create a function to run the tool.  I think.

Can anybody help with the function and connecting that function the the button?

Comment: So I think i solved this - there was no need to create another function, just simply put the statement: roadBuffer.submitJob(); into the oClick function.  So this was the final code:'var myButton = new Button({
               //label: "Click me!",
               onClick: function () {
                   // Do something:
                   roadBuffer.submitJob();
               }
           }, "BufferButton");'

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you solved your problem with a geoprocessing service, but you may find it much easier to do the buffer with the javascript API instead.  See example here.

```
var params = new ags.BufferParameters();
params.bufferSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
params.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
params.unit = ags.GeometryService.UNIT_FOOT;
params.unionResults = true;
params.distances = [5];
params.geometries = [fs.features[0].geometry];

Globals.GeometryService.buffer(params, geometryService_BufferCompleted, geometryService_Failed);
```